# Integration of Bloch equation in magnetic resonance

Tags: integration, differential-equations, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

From Bloch equation we have
\begin{equation}\label{bloch_01}
\tag{1}
\frac{d M_z}{dt} = \frac{M_0-M_z}{T_1}
\end{equation}
from there we can integrate and we get
\begin{equation}\label{bloch_02}
\tag{2}
M_0-M_z = e^{-\frac{t}{T_1}}e^c
\end{equation}
where $c$ is an integration constant. For $\alpha = 90^\circ$
$$
M_z = M_0(1-e^{-\frac{t}{T1}})
$$
Before integrating, I tried to go from (1) to (2) by separating variable s.t.:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d M_z}{dt} &= \frac{M_0-M_z}{T_1}\\
\frac{T_1}{dt} &= \frac{M_0-M_z}{d M_z}\\
\frac{dt}{T_1} &= \frac{d M_z }{M_0-M_z}\\
\ln{T_1} &= \ln{M_0-M_z}\\
\end{align*}
but I suspect it is wrong and could not go further. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** (thanks to answer below from @mikestone)

\begin{align*}
\frac{d M_z(t)}{dt} &= \frac{M_0-M_z(t)}{T_1}\\
\frac{T_1}{dt} &= \frac{M_0-M_z(t)}{d M_z}\\
\frac{dt}{T_1} &= \frac{d M_z(t)}{M_0-M_z(t)}\\
\frac{t}{T_1} &= -\ln({M_0-M_z(t)})+ c\\
-\frac{t}{T_1} &= \ln({M_0-M_z(t)})+ c\\
e^{-\frac{t}{T_1}} &=(M_0-M_z(t))e^c\\
e^{-\frac{t}{T_1}}e^{-c} &=M_0-M_z(t)\\
M_0-M_z(t) &= e^{-\frac{t}{T_1}}e^{-c}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_1$ is a constant, so your $\ln T_1$ is wrong. Also there is  a minus sign before $M_z$ in the penultimate line, so your last line *should* read
$$
  t/T_1= -\ln (M_0-M_z(t))+ c.
$$
Exponentiating then gives
$$
M_0-M_z(t)= e^{-t/T_1} e^{c}.
$$

Comment: many thanks for your answer @mikestone. Is the edit I wrote correct? If yes, writting $e^c$ and $e^{-c}$ is equivalent as $c$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes. Both are rebitrary constants.